# Node JS express install custom app structure/skeleton

Tags: node.js, express

Anyone know if I can save the app structure that I use often with the command line as:

```
express custom_build myapp
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would you like an archive of your directory? A version control? A tree representing the structure? What do you mean by 'save'?

Comment: @Ixe Reuse the same app structure in offline mode :)

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. Look at https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/bin/express, and you'll see that the assets are hard-coded into the binary. Put your skeleton into a git repository, and clone it to start a new project.